# What's the best way to throw a RuntimeException if a bunch of variables aren't initialized?

Tags: java

I have the following AppProperties class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class AppProperties {

    public static final String DIGITAL_ASSETS_UPLOADS_BUCKET;
    public static final String REGION;
    public static final String APP_PEEFIX;
    public static final String ACCOUNT_NUMBER;

    public static final String TEXTRACT_SSM_SNS_NAME;
    public static final String TEXTRACT_SSM_SQS_NAME;


    /**
     * Let's initialize the variables from the application.properties file
     */
    static {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(AppProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't retrieve the application.properties file from the classpath. ", e);
        }

        DIGITAL_ASSETS_UPLOADS_BUCKET = prop.getProperty("aws.bucket.digitalassetsuploads");
        REGION = prop.getProperty("aws.region");
        APP_PEEFIX = prop.getProperty("cdk.appprefix");
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER = prop.getProperty("aws.accountnumber");
        TEXTRACT_SSM_SNS_NAME = prop.getProperty("aws.ssm.sns.textract");
        TEXTRACT_SSM_SQS_NAME = prop.getProperty("aws.ssm.sqs.textract");

    }
}
```

What I would love to do is use an Annotation or some "magic" that would throw a RuntimeException if any of the variables aren't initialized or if any of the values are null. I know I can do a manual check on every variable but it's too dirty of an approach....Kotlin makes this too easy and I'm spoiled.

Is this possible?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler check if all the `static final`s are initialised at compile time?

Comment: OP wants a null check too

Answer (score 1):

Not "magic", just a function, but does what you want clearly and succinctly:

```
    static String getNonNullProperty(Properties props, String key) {
        String value = props.getProperty(key);
        if (value == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No value for '" + key + '"');
        }
        return value;
    }
...
        DIGITAL_ASSETS_UPLOADS_BUCKET = getNonNullProperty(prop, "aws.bucket.digitalassetsuploads");
        REGION = getNonNullProperty(prop, "aws.region");
        APP_PEEFIX = getNonNullProperty(prop, "cdk.appprefix");
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER = getNonNullProperty(prop, "aws.accountnumber");
        TEXTRACT_SSM_SNS_NAME = getNonNullProperty(prop, "aws.ssm.sns.textract");
        TEXTRACT_SSM_SQS_NAME = getNonNullProperty(prop, "aws.ssm.sqs.textract");
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should give you an error if you forgot to initialise a `static final` field.

As for throwing an exception when it is initialised to null, you can use [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)), which is almost like an "annotation". You can optionally supply an error message.

```
REGION = Objects.requireNonNull(prop.getProperty("aws.region"));
APP_PEEFIX = Objects.requireNonNull(
    prop.getProperty("cdk.appprefix"), "App prefix is null!"
);
```

This throws a `NullPointerException` if the value is null, which is a kind of `RuntimeException`.

Alternatively, since you are always using `getProperty` to initialise the properties, you can write a `@NotNull` method that wraps around it:

```
private static final Properties prop = new Properties();
@NotNull
private static getProperty(String key) {
    return prop.getProperty(key);
}
```

You can configure IntelliJ to generate a null check for this:

[image]

At runtime, an `ExceptionInInitializerError` will be thrown, which is not a `RuntimeException`, but there is an `IllegalStateException` as the cause, with an appropriate message.

Answer (score 0):

One option is [decorating](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20decorator%20pattern) `Properties` with a class that throws the exception on calling `getProperty()`

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class NonNullProperties extends Properties {
    private final Properties mProps;

    public NonNullProperties(Properties props) {
        mProps = props;
    }

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        String property = super.getProperty(key);
        if (property == null) {
            throw new  NullPointerException(key + " was null!");
        }
        
        return  property;
    }

    // OVERRIDE AND DELEGATE OTHER METHODS
}
```

Then the only thing you have to change in your code is wrapping the Properties class.

```
Properties prop = new NonNullProperties(new Properties());
```

Comment: This is heading in the right direction, but the underlying `Properties` should be encapsulated by the new class, not extended. We don't need/want the `Properties` interface, and this violates the contract of the overridden `getProperty()` method. No need for that when a single method in a wrapper meets the need.

Comment: I have no idea what this comment means. Properties is extended in this sample because it's a decorator - that's how the pattern works. Properties is not an interface. How don't you need/want the `Properties` _class_ when that's what the OP is using? What contract is being violated? No need for what? A single method in what wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Properties` in a simple helper that does what you want:

```java
public final class NonNullProperties {

  private final Properties properties;

  public NonNullProperties(Properties properties) {
    this.properties = Objects.requireNonNull(properties);
  }

  public String get(String name) {
    return Objects.requireNonNull(properties.getProperty(name), name);
  }
  
}
```

Your handling of the resource stream leaves the stream open, and missing configuration could be reported more clearly.

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream is = AppProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_NAME);
if (is == null) throw new UncheckedIOException(new FileNotFoundException(CONFIG_NAME));
try (is) {
  properties.load(is);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
}

NonNullProperties config = new NonNullProperties(properties);
DIGITAL_ASSETS_UPLOADS_BUCKET = config.get("aws.bucket.digitalassetsuploads");
...
```